# Transparent image click through in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a game which uses mostly DOM Elements. Now I have a problem.
DOM Elements are usally Rectangles. The problem is, that if I have an image with transparent parts over another image, the bottom image will not be clicked if you hit the transparent part of the overlying one.

I searched for some jQuery plugins for this problem and found some:

1. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parrythrust-1-0-0-transparent-image-clickthrough
2. http://plugins.jquery.com/pixelselect/

The problem here is, that the first plugin only detects click events.
The other one is more promising, because it can detect mouseover, mouseout, click and more, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Is there an other solution for this problem? Image Maps are not a solution because I don't think they can handle overlying stuff with different z-indexes.

Comment: consider using SVG instead, it's time to put SVG content into webpage nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [CSS Shapes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/)?

You can define your own perimeter for the element. Circles are pretty easy.

```
.element{
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

Be warned that currently, only Chrome 37+ support it, according to that article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a solution which works for more browsers.